# How can I make the Debian non-free image with drivers?

Tags: linux, debian

There are Linux distributions that are based on Debian.
I like Debian. And I don't want to use other distributions.
But every time you install, users are faced with driver issues.
For example, my virtual machine doesn't work correctly with Debian due to the lack of drivers.
We know about this image:
firmware-10.3.0-amd64-netinst.iso
But as I understand it, in any case, this doesn't include all drivers.
I support Debian, but I'm not a fan of free software.
I'd like to create an image that:
1. Will contain all possible drivers, or will load it depending on the device;
2. Will include non-free repositories.
I can configure my system, no problem. But I'm blind, and it will be difficult for me to do this if, for example, the audio driver isn't found.
How can I make such an image?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know your linux background level, but might I suggest Ubuntu to start with. Debian is not as friendly as Ubuntu and does not have many drivers because of proprietary issues. Ubuntu is just a fork of Debian. Also, more people use Ubuntu in general, therefore information is much easier to find due to larger forums. etc.
In the future, StackOverflow is generally used for specific code related issues. Although your question is fine it does not fit the stereotypical format, i.e. it better suited for a forum/discussion. good luck

Answer (score 1):

the best is add package non-free, it's in /etc/apt/sources.list 
in the console write 
nano /etc/apt/sources.list 
at the end of the line that have deb or deb-src add non-free 
finally apt update and reboot 
i did this in a laptop hp that have hardware private 
I hope it helps you